# How to use "as const satisfies" with array of objects to get "as const" benefits with type checking

Tags: typescript

Work as expected:

```
interface ExampleA {
  id: number;
  name: `S${string}`;
}
export const exampleA = {
  id: 8455,
  name: 'Savory'
} as const satisfies ExampleA;
```

Doesn't work :-(

```
interface ExampleB {
  id: number;
  name: `S${string}`;
}
export const exampleB = [
  {
    id: 8455,
    name: 'Savory'
  }
] as const satisfies ExampleB[];
```

Error for exampleB:

```
Type 'readonly [{ readonly id: 8455; readonly name: "Savory"; }]' does not satisfy the expected type 'ExampleB[]'.
  The type 'readonly [{ readonly id: 8455; readonly name: "Savory"; }]' is 'readonly' and cannot be assigned to the mutable type 'ExampleB[]'.ts(1360)
```

I read TypeScript 4.9 blog post and couple of GitHub issue from TypeScript repo and still have no idea what I'm doing wrong or if there another way to do what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When you use `as const` on an array, typescript thinks of it as `readonly`. So, you need to make your `satisfies` type `readonly`.

```
export const exampleB = [{...}] as const satisfies readonly ExampleB[];
```

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for. Quick meta question, I ran into another issue which I believe is out of scope of this question, how long do I need to wait to ask another question, asking because I heard there is a cooldown.

Comment: You should check [Rate limiting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/164900/919970).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75115839/use-tuple-type-with-as-const-and-satifies-operator-on-array-to-get-benefit-o